# Does Curse of Exhaustion and Possibility Storm hard lock your opponent out of casting anything?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does a [Curse of Exhaustion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Curse%20of%20Exhaustion) enchanting my opponent hard lock my opponent out of playing anything when there is a [Possibility Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Possibility%20Storm) in play?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a *total* lock, but it's a pretty strong lock. If they cast anything from their hand, then yes, Possibility Storm will exile it and give them a replacement that they can't cast. Note that Possibility Storm only applies to casting from their hand, though. There's plenty of mechanics that cast a card from other zones (e.g. flashback, suspend, madness) that can get around this combo.